# ¿Cómo corregir dependencias circulares en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Tengo un proyecto en [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) con una estructura de archivos más o menos así:

```
...
public/
src/
    ...
    core/
        ajax-interceptors.js
        constants.js
        global-ui.js
        index.js
        redux-store.js
        service-mocker.js
    ...
.eslintrc.json
.gitignore
package.json
...
```

El archivo `index.js` contiene lo siguiente:

```
// @scripts
----------------------------------------------------------
// Aquí aparece el primer error
import { addAjaxInterceptors } from './ajax-interceptors'; 
// Dependency cycle detected.eslint(import/no-cycle)
----------------------------------------------------------
import { initializeGlobalUI } from './global-ui';
import { initializeReduxStore } from './redux-store';
import { initializeServiceMocker } from './service-mocker';

const initializeApp = () => {
    const store = initializeReduxStore();
    const serviceMocker = initializeServiceMocker();
    const globalUI = initializeGlobalUI(store);

    addAjaxInterceptors();
    loadFonts();

    const core = {
        globalUI,
        serviceMocker,
        store
    };

    return core;
};

export const {
    globalUI,
    store
} = initializeApp();
```

El archivo `ajax-interceptors.js` contiene lo siguiente:

```
// @packages
import axios from 'axios';

// @scripts
// Aquí aparece el mismo error (Dependency cycle detected.eslint(import/no-cycle))
// Estoy llamando el objeto globalUI desde el index
// puesto que ya lo inicializé con el store de redux necesario para trabajar
import { globalUI } from '.';

const addResponseInterceptors = () => {
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(response.data, 'data')) {
                const {
                    data,
                    message,
                    messageType
                } = response.data;

                if (message && messageType) {
                    globalUI.showToastNotification({
                        msg: message,
                        type: messageType
                    });
                }

                return data;
            }

            return response.data;
        },
        (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );
};

export const addAjaxInterceptors = () =>
    addResponseInterceptors();
```

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error de dependencias circulares sin que afecte la arquitectura que tengo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalmente cuando hay dependencies circulares, es un indicativo de que la arquitectura no está bien concebida (hay otras razones, pero, como sucede en tu caso, esta suele ser la más común). Lo que te está sucediendo es lo siguiente:

```
Módulo 1 => importa a Módulo 2 => importa a Módulo 1
```

Cualquier solución que intentes aplicar para solventar esto, incluye una refactorización del código, y esto implica que tendrás que variar un poco tu arquitectura.

Una solución es que muevas la lógica del módulo 2 al módulo 1 pero entiendo que esto no es ideal porque los módulos tienen funciones diferentes. Otra solución es que crees un tercer módulo, así que en vez de la dependencia anterior, sería algo como:

```
Módulo 1 => importa a Módulo 3
Módulo 2 => importa a Módulo 3
```

Siguiendo estas recomendaciones puedes encontrar disímiles soluciones, pero una que se me ocurre de entre las tantas posibles es la siguiente:

Fichero core.js:

```
import { initializeGlobalUI } from './global-ui';
import { initializeReduxStore } from './redux-store';
import { initializeServiceMocker } from './service-mocker';

const store = initializeReduxStore();
const serviceMocker = initializeServiceMocker();
const globalUI = initializeGlobalUI(store);

export const core = {
    globalUI,
    serviceMocker,
    store
};
```

Fichero ajax-interceptors.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { core } from './core';

const addResponseInterceptors = () => {
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(response.data, 'data')) {
                const {
                    data,
                    message,
                    messageType
                } = response.data;

                if (message && messageType) {
                    core.globalUI.showToastNotification({
                        msg: message,
                        type: messageType
                    });
                }

                return data;
            }

            return response.data;
        },
        (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );
};

export const addAjaxInterceptors = () =>
    addResponseInterceptors();
```

Fichero index.js:

```
import { core } from './core';
import { addAjaxInterceptors } from './ajax-interceptors';

const initializeApp = () => {

    addAjaxInterceptors();
    loadFonts();

    // Haz lo que necesites con core  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías pasar el requerimiento como parámetro:

```
addAjaxInterceptors(globalUI);
```

Así no necesitarías importarlo en `ajax-interceptors.js`.

Otra opción podría ser sería mantener una variable estática en `global-ui` que mantenga el valor de `initializeGlobalUI(store);` y así puedas importarla con algo como:

```
import { getGlobalUI } from './global-ui';
```

Comment: No quisiera que `globalUI` fuera un argumento dependiente de mi función `addAjaxInterceptors()`, pero tendré en cuenta tu respuesta.

Comment: @Jorius revisa mi última edición, si te sirve.